# pymongo: insert_one() is running but isn't adding anything to mongodb database?

Tags: python, mongodb, pycharm, pymongo

I'm trying to upload a .txt file to a mongodb database collection using PyCharm, but nothing is appearing inside of the collection? Here's the script I'm using at the moment:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()
db = client.memorizer_data # use a database called "memorizer_data"
collection = db.english # and inside that DB, a collection called "english"

with open('7_1_1.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read() # read the txt file
    name = '7_1_1.txt'

# build a document to be inserted
text_file_doc = {"file_name": name, "contents": text}

# insert the contents into the "file" collection
collection.insert_one(text_file_doc)
```

PyCharm gets through the script with no errors, I've also tried printing the acknowledged attribute just to see what comes up:

```
result = collection.insert_one(text_file_doc)
print(result.acknowledged)
```

Which is giving me `True`. I wasn't sure if I was actually connecting to my database, so I tried `db.list_collection_names()` and my collection 'english' is in the list, so as far as I can tell I am connecting with it?

I'm a newbie to MongoDB so I realize I've probably gone about things the wrong way. At the moment I'm just trying to get the script working for a single .txt file before uploading everything my project is using to the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think there's nothing in the collection? Two ways to check;

In your pymongo code, add a final debug line:

```
print(collection.find_one())
```

Or, in the mongodb shell:

```
use memorizer_data
db.english.findOne()
```

Comment: When I log into mongodb and view the collection in my cluster, it says 0 documents so I just assumed that the document wasn't being added. But when I use print(collection.find_one()) as you've suggested, the document is appearing - so it seems like the script is in fact adding the document! Sounds like I need to take a little more time understanding what's what in mongodb before I move forward with the database part of my project haha. Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you say "it says 0 documents", what command are you using? Did you use the commands I suggested? Make sure you definitely have the right server / database / connection string.

Comment: I'm just basing the 0 documents off of what's on the mongodb website. When I log in and look at database deployments I'm clicking 'browse collections' then when I click on the database and the 'english' collection, it says 'Total documents: 0'. So that's why I assumed that nothing was getting uploaded.

Comment: Ok odd ... an explanation could be you're accessing different databases.